# Easy way of editing Microsoft excel cells in Java

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to see if there is a simple way of editing excel cells with Java. I know vaguely that you can use APIs to edit excel documents. I say vaguely because I have only read briefly about it and not done it myself.

The exact situation is a friend of mine is trying to update his karaoke excel list. He inputted all of the data in like this in a single cell or column:

Song Title; Artist; Track Number; Genre

The alteration he is wanting is to have it the text between the semi-colons different columns such as:

SONG Title          Artist         Track Number         Genre

I told him I would help him because it's the summer break and I don't have anything else to do plus I'm a software engineering student so it should be good practice. If anyone can just point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Export it as a "CSV" file.  Process the file, replacing all the ";" with "," re-import into Excel...You could also use a CVS library to load the file manipulate the results, as any "," will be used to break the content into columns, so you could open it using ";" as the delimiter and then possibly save it back out with "," is the delimiter...

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+api+excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Apache commons library for [editing microsoft documents](http://poi.apache.org/):

One of its components allows you to edit excel sheets. [This quick guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) will get you started.

Its on the maven central repository, you can download (the excel editing API) it with the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll start reading the guide to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Apache POI library:
http://poi.apache.org/

You can edit XLS AND XLSX documents